# how to play Lottie animations with uri in react native?

Tags: animation, react-native, lottie

how can i play Lottie animations from server(uri) in react native?
i could play animations from my project assets but when i use source={{uri:"https://...data here..."}} i face an error... even i downloaded json files to phone and try to play then from phone storage but faced an error too!
here the code:

```js
<LottieView style={{ width: "28%", marginTop: "5%", alignContent: "center", alignItems: "center", 
 alignSelf: "center" }}
 source={{uri:"file://///data/user/0/com.duststudio/files/vv/test2.json"}} 
 autoPlay
 loop />
```

i really need it...i would be so happy and thankful if anyone knows how to do it :)

Comment: In Lottie animation, what I recall is that they add those animated photos connect in json format, which means inserting the https within the json instead of calling https in source should work

Comment: Ah would you please write me a very simple example?

Comment: @MahdiEslami were you able to figure it out? I can't seem to load animation with URI as well. The source I'm using is `source={{ uri: "https://assets1.lottiefiles.com/private_files/lf30_GjhcdO.json" }}`

Comment: No i wasn't....i tried also downloading Lottie animation and loading it from phone storage but it just worked when it's fixed and it wouldn't show it immediately after downloading it...i migrated to Flutter and it's awesome... Flutter Lottie library gives access to Lottie json files also with uri but the fps is less than 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found it...i just found the way :')
you just need to fetch JSON of Lottie Animation then set a state for it, check this out:

```js
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
    import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';


   export default function App(){
     const [LottieAnim, setLottieAnim] = useState()
    
     useEffect(() => {
            fetch('https://test.ir/test.json', {
                method: "GET",
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseData) => {
                    console.log(responseData);
                    setLottieAnim(responseData)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        }, [])

return(

        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              {LottieAnim ? <LottieView source={LottieAnim} style={{ width: "50%" }} autoPlay loop /> : (null)}
         </View>

)}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also set the uri by

```
<LottieView
      autoPlay
      style={{
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
      }}
      source={{uri : "https://res.cloudinary.com/etc.."}}
    />
```

Comment: After battling this for about 2 hours, I realised the issue was I didn't set a width and height 

If you don't set a width and height, the URI option will not work!!